# Does inclusion of Z into p-adic numbers induce a split short exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the $p$-adic numbers. We have a canonical embedding $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p$. This induces a short exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$
Does this sequence split? I suspect, that it does not, but I couldn't think of a good argument.

Comment: Exact sequence of what? $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Comment: If $p > 2$, what would $1/2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ map to?

Comment: @Mark sorry yes, I have added this in question now.

Comment: @ronno, thanks that is a good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a sequence of groups, i.e. $\Bbb{Z}$-modules. In this case, it is not split. Being split would be equivalent to having a section $\Bbb{Z}_p\to \Bbb{Z}$ such that composing with the map from the sequence yields the identity on $\Bbb{Z}$. However, there exists no such group homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}_p\to \Bbb{Z}$. Indeed, to compose to the identity on $\Bbb{Z}$ we need that $1\mapsto 1$, but if we pick any prime $q\neq p$, we see that the image of $\frac1q$ (which is a $p$-adic integer) cannot be $0$, as adding it to itself $q$ times yields $1$. However, no element in $\Bbb{Z}$ has that property, so such a map cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!